# Short interruptions during audio playback

Tags: flutter, audio

We got short interruptions during audio playback from iOS streaming (streaming is taken from AzureCast https://s.lovelyoneapp.ru/public/lively)

This is Flutter App

Video example https://youtube.com/shorts/GVm4MFjnmEg?feature=share

We tried to update app but doesen help, other app don't support background mode. Could the problem be caused by audio buffering?